# Making forms using flex in Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, flexbox

Hi I'm making a Rails app and making a signup page using rails and flex.
Below is the form I'm imagining right now.
[image]

Below is the code I have for my Rails and they are organized in very weird manner.

code:

```
<%= form_for(resource,
               as: resource_name,
               :class => "footer",
               :html => { :class => "footer" },
               url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

          <!--First Name-->
         <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; order:1">
        <div style="margin-right:20px">
        <%= f.label :first_name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name,autofocus: true, :class => "textfield textfield-control vertical-offset--teensy" %>
                            </div>

        <div>
        <%= f.label :last_name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, :class => "textfield textfield-control vertical-offset--teensy" %>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div style="display: flex;flex-direction:column; order: 2; flex-grow:1">
        <div>
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.email_field :email,autofocus: true, :class => "textfield textfield-control vertical-offset--teensy" %>
        </div>

        <div>
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
         <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "textfield textfield-control vertical-offset--teensy" %>
        </div>

       <div>
       <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,autocomplete: "off",:class => "textfield textfield-control vertical-offset--teensy" %>
        </div>
        </div>


      <!--Sign up button-->
      <div class="signup-container vertical-offset--tiny">
        <button class="button button--long button--primary"> Sign up </button>
      </div>

  <% end %>
```

This ends up being:
[image]

I would love to get advice on flex part to make it like below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input`s were occupying the entire width until they were nested in their own individual divs, in which case they acted like they were display: `inline-block`.

Here's a solution that makes the `input`s occupy the entire width of their container and automatically spaces everything out with a flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/jpm45egq/

Comment: Can you add an example with labels on top of textfields? When I insert labels, they start killing the styling :/

Comment: Stuck labels on top of the inputs and everything appears to be in order... https://jsfiddle.net/jpm45egq/1/ you'll have to post the source, something else must be happening.